# Session Issue while hosting Asp.net website in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I built a ASP.NET website which conducts a online exam and displays score. I published it locally and hosted in the IIS. Then I connected my system through lan with another question. I answered the first 5 questions from my laptop. And when I tried to access the website from the other laptop it starts from the 5th Question instead of the first question.

```
     public partial class MainPage : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
     public static int Qnum=1, Score=0,Count=0;
    public static List<int> answered=new List<int>();
    private SQLconnect sqlconnect = new SQLconnect();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["Score"] = Score;
            fnMCq();
        }
    }

    public void fnMCq()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sqlconnect.Connection_string = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn_MCQ"];

            string query = "select * from Questions where qid='" + Qnum + "'";
            dt = sqlconnect.getDataTable(query);
            string[] array = dt
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(row => row.Field<string>("question"))
                  .ToArray();
            Question.Text = array[0];
            query = "Select * from Answers where qid='" + Qnum + "'";
            dt.Clear();
            dt = sqlconnect.getDataTable(query);
            Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            values.Add(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString(), "1");
            values.Add(dt.Rows[0][2].ToString(), "2");
            values.Add(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString(), "3");
            values.Add(dt.Rows[0][4].ToString(), "4");
            Answers.DataSource = values;
            Answers.DataTextField = "key";
            Answers.DataValueField = "Value";
            Answers.DataBind();
            fnHideSubmit();
            if (Qnum == 1)

                btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
            else
                btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
            if (Qnum == 20)
                btnNext.Enabled = false;
            else
                btnNext.Enabled = true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
         {
             Session["error"] = e.Message;
            Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx");

        }

    }

    protected void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isexamover())
        {
            Qnum = Qnum - 1;
            fnMCq();
        }
    }

    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isexamover())
        {
            Qnum = Qnum + 1;
            fnMCq();
        }
    }

    public void fnUpdateScore()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn_MCQ"]);

        int selectedanswer,answer;
       selectedanswer=Convert.ToInt32(Answers.SelectedValue);
       string query = "select answer from questions where qid='"+Qnum+"'";
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,conn);
        conn.Open();
         sqlconnect.Connection_string = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn_MCQ"];

          answer =Convert.ToInt32( cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) ;
          if (answer == selectedanswer)
          { 
              Score = Score + 1; 
              Session["Score"] = Score; 
          }
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        answered.Add(Qnum);
        fnHideSubmit();
        fnUpdateScore();
        if (!qbound())
        {
            if (!isexamover())
            {
                ++Qnum;
                fnMCq();
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Score"] = Score;
                Response.Redirect("ScoreDisplay.aspx");
            }

        }

    }
    public void fnHideSubmit()
    {  
        foreach (int i in answered)
        {
            if (i == Qnum)
            {
                btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
                break;
            }
            else
                btnSubmit.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    public bool qbound()
    {
        if (Qnum == 1 || Qnum == 20)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
    public bool isexamover()
    {
        if (answered.Count == 20)
        {
            Session["Score"] = Score;
            Response.Redirect("ScoreDisplay.aspx");
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear!!!!!

Comment: Please add some code to better explain the problem.

Comment: I never setup any session @Hanlet .... I believe session is created automatically everytime a request is sent to the server. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have comes from storing everything in static fields:

```
public static int Qnum=1, Score=0,Count=0;
public static List<int> answered=new List<int>();
```

This means that there is only one instance of these fields. These fields are tied to the class, not a specific instance of that class.

In order to solve this, you could store these in the `Session`, which will allow you to remember the values across several page requests within a single session.

Answer (score 0):

When using static on a variable, .NET will reserve a spot in memory for that variable.  I am thinking that when a new user tries to take the quiz while anyone else is, it will reference that same variable location which has the count of the other user.

```
public int Qnum=1, Score=0,Count=0;
public List<int> answered=new List<int>();
```

Comment: So what could be a alternative to this scenario?

Comment: The Session variable and PageState variables are unique to the user.  So, the Session variable will preserve data until the "Session_End" global method is called and the PageState will preserve data through PostBacks.

Comment: Note that `Session_End` is not guaranteed to be called. Don't build something that relies on sessions neatly being closed with a call to it.

Comment: So, once all of the information has been placed into the variable, save them into unique Session states (keys).  Then, check to see if that Session key is null, and if it is not, use that instead of creating a new variable.